# Why am I getting a SpringFramework UnexpectedRollbackException?

Tags: spring, transactions, confluence

I am getting the following Spring Framework error message:

```
Invocation of getLogoForGlobalConext() in class $Proxy44 threw exception
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException:
Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
at template/includes/macros.vm line 1651, column 43
```

I opened `macros.vm` and looked up line 1651 and it looks like this:

```
#set ($globalLogo = $spaceManager.getLogoForGlobalContext());
```

From my research it looks like `$Proxy44` is actually the `$spaceManager` variable (or an instance of `DefaultSpaceManager.java`).

This message appears randomly and when the web app tries to download an image/attachment sitting somewhere on the web server / database.

The attachmentmanager is governed by Spring's Transaction Management and the following transaction attributes are used when an image/attachment is downloaded:

1. propagation - for all methods in the attachment manager
2. propagation and read-only - for all methods in attachment manager starting with "get".

The attributes are defined in [Spring Framework - Chapter 9. Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html).
What I am thinking is I need to set a timeout on the transactions (like set it to infinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out one of the getter methods was performing a write to database.  Specifically, it was updating the cache with some information every few minutes. When this update occurred, the `UnexpectedRollbackException` was thrown. Since this transaction is supposed to be "read only" as defined by the transaction attributes mentioned above, we are not allowed to perform updates during a getter operation.

I changed the getter method to not perform any updates to cache and to simply use the cache even if it expired, and the error goes away.

Hope this helps someone else.